# How to interpret brackets surrounding a Interface string Property That Maps to an Object Type Literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand what the corresponding javascript object is that would fit the type definition given for [`[propertyName: string]:...`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/63e173c806bdfc879d13a0069debb73f4a757bf6/src/validation-schema/ValidationSchema.ts#L20).  If you click the link it shows the entire definition.

Also how should we interpret the brackets around `[propertyName: string]:...`?

Comment: It's an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), and the bracketed stuff is a string index signature.

Comment: OK - So essentially the whole thing maps to a javascript Object instance / associative array?

Comment: @Ole no it's signifies the allowed key, value pairs and the types of their values. For example you can declare an interface that has an index signature of members. Which restricts a certain type of values for the interface members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an index signature that says the object can contain any fields with any name, but values of all fields must be of the type specified after `:`

Let's consider a simplified example :

```
interface Indexable {
    [properyName: string]: {
        isValid: boolean
    }
}

let valid: Indexable = {
    anyName: { isValid: true }, 
    anyOtherName : { isValid: false }
};

let invalid: Indexable = {
    invalidFields: { isValid_: true }, // no isValid field 
    excessFields: { isValid: true, unexpectedProp: 0 }, // Object literal may only specify known properties
};
let invalidType: Indexable = {
    numberField: 0  // 'numberField' is incompatible with index signature.
};
```